# Why do k-algebra homomorphisms commute with polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I have read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200160/when-does-a-polynomial-ring-homomorphism-commute-with-scalar-multiplication), but I still am left with the doubt. In the proof by Hartshorne on page 19 that there is a natural bijection $\alpha$ between homsets between affine varieties and homsets between their (flipped) coordinate ring and ring of regular functions, the equality at the bottom of the pages uses this fact crucially.

In particular, I think you need that

$f(h(\overline{x_1})(P), ... h(\overline{x_n})(P)) = h(f(\overline{x_1},...,\overline{x_n}))(P)$

Where h is a $k$-algebra homomorphism between the rings of regular functions on the affine varieties $Y$ and $X$, $f$ is a polynomial in $I(Y)$, each $\overline{x_i}$ is the image of a coordinate $x_i$ in the coordinate ring $A(Y)$, and $P$ is a point in $X$, the other affine variety.

In most of the proofs I see online it seems an “obvious” detail concerning how a ring homomorphism that preserves units is a $k$-algebra homomorphism (because scalars work out), but I guess I am confused as to how exactly an arbitrary polynomial could possibly preserve units.

(I am sure I am looking at this the wrong way, I just want clarification as to how. Perhaps it is because of the isomorphism between $A(Y) \cong \mathcal{O}(Y)$ for affine varieties that we can consider the LHS a “compatible” k-algebra to begin with? Also could someone clear up what exactly the map $\overline{ }$ that sends a coordinate to its image in the appropriate polynomial ring is?)

Comment: Where do you see the need to have a polynomial preserve units? Have you tried writing this out in an example?

Comment: Well I thought that the polynomial $f$ in question was the one that had to commute with the k-algebra morphism $h$ and somehow it ($f$, that is) also being a k-algebra morphism could give us this. It seems to me the polynomial, even a homogeneous one, will just end up adding up the unit as many times as there are variables, to give $n* 1$. I am guessing somehow this polynomial is to be interpreted *as the scalar* that will commute with the k-algebra morphism $h$, but I don’t see the path to this interpretation easily.

Comment: I think I see a few points of confusion that need to be worked out. Maybe we can discuss this in chat?

Comment: Ok that would be great! How do I access that?edit: I think I found it?

Comment: I created a room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117794/commuting-k-alg-homs-and-polynomials You could also join the main MSE chat here, if you want others' inputs as well: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics